# VBA - Unable to map drive to sharepoint on another computer

Tags: vba, excel, sharepoint, connection

I'm mapping to the company's sharepoint drive using VBA. The intention is to save local file to sharepoint, and delete local file and unmapped the drive after success.

On my machine(Windows 10 64bits), the code works perfectly fine, successfully mapped the drive, created folder and file, successfully uploaded to sharepoint and unmap the drive.

However, when I run the same excel workbook that contains the same code on my colleague's computer(Window 7), it failed. There's no error being shown, except that it keeps on loading and loading until Excel **Not Responsive**. I tried manually mapping the drive, it success.

I tried to debug and found out that the code stops (keeps on loading) at `MsgBox "Hello"` but could not figure out what's missing.

**Both are using Excel 2016**

Any help and suggestions are appreciated. let me know if more info is needed. Thanks in advance.

**This is my vba code**

```
Sub imgClicked()

Dim fileName As String

Dim SharePointLib As String
Dim MyPath As String
Dim folderPath As String
Dim objNet As Object
Dim copyPath As String
Dim copyFilePath As String

folderPath = Application.ThisWorkbook.path
MyPath = Application.ThisWorkbook.FullName

Dim objFSO As Object
Dim strMappedDriveLetter As String
Dim strPath As String
Dim spPath As String

strPath = "https://company.com/sites/test/test 123/" 'example path
spPath = AvailableDriveLetter + ":\test.xlsm" 'example path
copyPath = folderPath + "\copyPath\"

'Add reference if missing
Call AddReference

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

With objFSO

strMappedDriveLetter = IsAlreadyMapped(.GetParentFolderName(strPath))

If Not Len(strMappedDriveLetter) > 0 Then

  strMappedDriveLetter = AvailableDriveLetter

  If Not MapDrive(strMappedDriveLetter, .GetParentFolderName(strPath)) Then

    MsgBox "Failed to map SharePoint directory", vbInformation, "Drive Mapping Failure"
     Exit Sub

  End If

 End If

 ' Check file/folder path If statement here

End With

Set objFSO = Nothing

End Sub
```

**Code for getting available drive**

```
  ' Returns the available drive letter starting from Z
 Public Function AvailableDriveLetter() As String

' Returns the last available (unmapped) drive letter, working backwards from Z:

Dim objFSO As Object
Dim i As Long

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

For i = Asc("Z") To Asc("A") Step -1

Select Case objFSO.DriveExists(Chr(i))

  Case True

  Case False

    Select Case Chr(i)

      Case "C", "D"     ' Not actually necessary - .DriveExists should return True anyway...

      Case Else

        AvailableDriveLetter = Chr(i)

        Exit For

    End Select

End Select

Next i

Set objFSO = Nothing
 MsgBox "This is the next available drive: " + AvailableDriveLetter ' returns Z drive
 MsgBox "Hello" ' After this msgBox, starts loading until Not Responsive
End Function
```

**Function to Map drive**

```
Public Function MapDrive(strDriveLetter As String, strDrivePath As String) As Boolean

Dim objNetwork As Object

If Len(IsAlreadyMapped(strDrivePath)) > 0 Then Exit Function

Set objNetwork = CreateObject("WScript.Network")

objNetwork.MapNetworkDrive strDriveLetter & ":", strDrivePath, False

MapDrive = True
MsgBox "Successfully Created the Drive!"
Set objNetwork = Nothing

End Function
```

**Code for MappedDrive**

```
Public Function GetMappedDrives() As Variant

' Returns a 2-D array of (1) drive letters and (2) network paths of all mapped drives on the users machine

Dim objFSO As Object
Dim objDrive As Object
Dim arrMappedDrives() As Variant
Dim i As Long

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

ReDim arrMappedDrives(1 To 2, 1 To 1)

For i = Asc("A") To Asc("Z")

If objFSO.DriveExists(Chr(i)) Then

  Set objDrive = objFSO.GetDrive(Chr(i))

  If Not IsEmpty(arrMappedDrives(1, UBound(arrMappedDrives, 2))) Then

    ReDim Preserve arrMappedDrives(1 To 2, 1 To UBound(arrMappedDrives, 2) + 1)

  End If

  arrMappedDrives(1, UBound(arrMappedDrives, 2)) = Chr(i)            ' Could also use objDrive.DriveLetter...
  arrMappedDrives(2, UBound(arrMappedDrives, 2)) = objDrive.ShareName
End If

Next i

GetMappedDrives = arrMappedDrives

Set objDrive = Nothing
Set objFSO = Nothing

End Function

Public Function IsAlreadyMapped(strPath As String) As String

' Tests if a given network path is already mapped on the users machine
' (Returns corresponding drive letter or ZLS if not found)

Dim strMappedDrives() As Variant
Dim i As Long

strMappedDrives = GetMappedDrives

 For i = LBound(strMappedDrives, 2) To UBound(strMappedDrives, 2)

  If LCase(strMappedDrives(2, i)) Like LCase(strPath) Then

  IsAlreadyMapped = strMappedDrives(1, i)

    Exit For

  End If

  Next i

  Set objNetwork = Nothing

  End Function
```

**Add Reference**

```
Sub AddReference()
 'Macro purpose:  To add a reference to the project using the GUID for the
 'reference library

Dim strGUID As String, theRef As Variant, i As Long

 'Update the GUID you need below.
strGUID = "{420B2830-E718-11CF-893D-00A0C9054228}"

 'Set to continue in case of error
On Error Resume Next

 'Remove any missing references
For i = ThisWorkbook.VBProject.References.Count To 1 Step -1
    Set theRef = ThisWorkbook.VBProject.References.Item(i)
    If theRef.isbroken = True Then
        ThisWorkbook.VBProject.References.Remove theRef
    End If
Next i

 'Clear any errors so that error trapping for GUID additions can be evaluated
Err.Clear

 'Add the reference
ThisWorkbook.VBProject.References.AddFromGuid _
GUID:=strGUID, Major:=1, Minor:=0

 'If an error was encountered, inform the user
Select Case Err.Number
Case Is = 32813
     'Reference already in use.  No action necessary
Case Is = vbNullString
     'Reference added without issue
Case Else
     'An unknown error was encountered, so alert the user
    MsgBox "A problem was encountered trying to" & vbNewLine _
    & "add or remove a reference in this file" & vbNewLine & "Please check the " _
    & "references in your VBA project!", vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "Error!"
End Select
On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

Comment: Which versions of Excel are each one running (the one that works and the one that doesn't)?  Do you know on which of those 4 procedures the system is becoming nonresponsive?

Comment: @ashleedawg hi, sorry forgot to mention the version of excel. Already updated the question. All are using Excel 2016. The system became non-responsive after getting the available drive.

Comment: also procedure `AddReference` is missing from your code sample (only relevant if you know for sure that it's one of these procedures causing the hang)

Comment: @ashleedawg Yes. I removed that part cause I afraid codes are too long. I did check the Tools -> References. It was correct. I will still added in since you mention about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Procedure `imgClicked` is calling function `AvailableDriveLetter` multiple times.  Remember that the function has to execute each time you refer to it.

I ran `imgClicked` (assuming that's the procedure you start with) and I was told, *twice*, `"Next available letter = Z"` and `"Hello"` and then it crashed Excel (perhaps getting stuck in a loop of creating FileSystem objects to look for an available drive letter?)

Try assigning `AvailableDriveLetter` to a variable (string) at the beginning of the procedure and referring to the variable each time you need the value, and see if you still have the issue.

(Remember to save before execution -- I get frustrated when troubleshooting "application hanging" issues because I keep forgetting to save my changes and then lose them on the crash!)

If this doesn't work, add a breakpoint (<kbd>F9</kbd>) on the `End Function` line after your "Hello" box and see if the code stops there.  (I have trouble believing the `MsgBox` or `End Function` are the culprit.)  If not, which procedure runs after that?

**One more thing whether the issue is resolved or not:**

> Add `Option Explicit` at the very beginning of your module and then `Compile` the project and fix your missing variable declaration(s).
>
> This is recommended whenever troubleshooting an issue as a means to eliminate variable declaration issues as a possible cause.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but the working one (mine) does shown `"Next available letter = Z"` and `"Hello"` **twice** and did not crash. The not working one shown `"Next available letter = Z"` and `"Hello"` **Once** and crashed.

Comment: Ok, still add that line of code to eliminate that as an issue. Do you know how?  If the machines have different RAM & CPU, one could be more likely to crash with the same code.  Also, when it becomes unresponsive, how are you ending it?  Have you tried rebooting the problem machine and seeing if the problem still occurs?  Object issues can cause memory leaks and forcing an application to exit can cause multiple instances to remain in the background.  I once found 25 copies of Outlook running in the background, once for each time I ran a sub, because I forgot a **`Set _Object_ = Nothing`**  :-)

Comment: Thanks for the sharing. That `Option Explicit` helps me to find a typo for my variable (variable is not related to the question) and explaining the RAM & CU. I will tried your recommendations when my colleagues is free(his using the computer now).

Comment: ...and missing obejct declaration for `objNetwork` in `MapDrive`, I believe?

Comment: ... needs `Dim objNetwork as Object`(see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/creating-object-variables?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) ...probably not the issue but should be fixed on both copies of the code anyhow, especially when diagnosing nonresponsiveness (since it could be caused by memory issue).  Just leave `Option Explicit` in there (all modules in the project) and Compile repeatedly until you don't get any warnings.

Comment: Also `strMappedDrives` has  `Set objnetwork = Nothing` but doesn't use `objnetwork`.  Is that line missing from elsewhere?

Comment: Hi, just managed to check with my colleague's computer. We are both using 8G RAM so it should be fine, I suppose? I also edited the codes according to your recommendations. Will test again tomorrow. Really hate it when it works perfectly on my com but not others and I need to debug using their com which is so inconvenience...